# Save the value of a service in a variable

Tags: angularjs

I must fill a combo to be able to select the value that the user wanted I have managed to do this with the data stored in an array, the next step is to consult a service and use the return values

```
<html>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="text">ObjectType:</label>
             <input type="text" ng-model="type" ng-keyup="complete(type)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
             <ul class="list-group">
                    li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in filterType" ng-click="fillTextbox(data)">{{data}}</li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</html>
```

```
var app = angular.module("Trace", []);
app.controller('TraceControlles', function ($scope, $http) {
    //$scope.typeList = ["integration", "none"];
    $scope.typeList = [];
    $scope.loadTypes = function () {
        $http.get("/api/Trace/GetObjectType")
           .then(function (responce) {
                $scope.typeList = responce.data;
            }, function errorCallback(responce) {
            });
    }
    $scope.complete = function (string) {
        var output = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.typeList, function (type) {
            if (type.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                output.push(type);
            }
        });
        $scope.filterType = output;
    }
    $scope.fillTextbox = function (string) {
        $scope.type = string;
        $scope.filterType = null;
    }
});
```

146/5000

When running the web api the service return values are not loaded, the browser does not mark any syntax error or anything like that.

Comment: `li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in filterType" ng-click="fillTextbox(data)">{{data}}</li>` check this line  where is `<` this

Comment: Yes, this only is a copy error, in my proyec this line its okay, the problem is in angular code

Comment: did you tried by seeing the response in network tab ?

Comment: Do you mean if the service returns the values correctly? if I provide my service with postman and the values are obtained correctly the result is the folowing:   
 [
    {
        "type": "Integration"
    },
    {
        "type": "None"
    }
]

Comment: Not sure if this is a copy paste thing from your example, but you're not actually calling `$scope.loadTypes()` anywhere in the controller.

Comment: According to me it is not necessary to send it to call since it is executed with the load of the web site, besides that of which it happened its value to the variable:
$ scope.loadTypes = function () {
             $ http.get ("/ api / Trace / GetObjectType")
                 .then (function (responce) {
                     $ scope.typeList = responce.data;
                 }, function errorCallback (responce) {

                 });
         }
Which I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it

Comment: If you were doing a `$scope.$onInit = loadTypes` with the appropriate version of Angular then it would be called automatically.  But without actually calling `$scope.loadTypes()` it will not be done, and therefore the network request won't be completed (hence the empty `typeList` when not using the hard coded array.  There is nothing wrong with the way you're declaring the loadTypes function.